# Convert field timestamp data to a java.sql Date in jooq

Tags: java, mysql, jooq

I retrieve timestamp type data from the mysql table. but I just need to return only the date part of this timestamp. Tried in convering timestamp to a date data type. But in jooq this gives some errors.Here is what I retrieve

```
 Field<Timestamp> transaction_date = LINKLK_TRANSACTIONS.MODIFIED_AT.as("transaction_date");
```

Comment: "this gives some errors" is never enough information. What *exactly* are the errors? And where is your code which tries performing the conversion? Given that a timestamp is just an instant in time, which could represent different dates in different time zones, which time zone are you interested in?

Comment: Actually I need a proper way to conversion. JOOQ Field<Timestamp> can't convert to a date. Incompatible data type

Comment: That doesn't answer my comment at all. You said you've tried something to convert the value, and you got errors - so what did you try, and what was the error? And do you understand my point about time zones?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This cannot work:

> ```
> Field<Timestamp> transaction_date = LINKLK_TRANSACTIONS.MODIFIED_AT.as("transaction_date");
> ```

All you're doing is renaming your column to a different name that happens to contain the name "date". You have to use MySQL's `date()` function, for instance

```
Field<Date> transaction_date = DSL.date(LINKLK_TRANSACTIONS.MODIFIED_AT);
```

Or you can cast your `Field`:

```
Field<Date> transaction_date = LINKLK_TRANSACTIONS.MODIFIED_AT.cast(Date.class);
```

There are many other options to do the same, but the above will be sufficient for your particular use-case.